# How can I make the localhost connect? Dash resufes connection

Tags: python, plotly-dash

This is the final project of a python course, I tried to run it but the localhost refuses the connection and I don't know why. I tried different things regarding the localhost the port and such changing it but it shows the same. Hopefully someone can guide through this and fix the problem so I can submit the assignment.

```
# Import required libraries
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from dash import no_update

# Create a dash application
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
JupyterDash.infer_jupyter_proxy_config()

# REVIEW1: Clear the layout and do not display exception till callback gets executed
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

# Read the airline data into pandas dataframe
airline_data =  pd.read_csv('https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DV0101EN-SkillsNetwork/Data%20Files/airline_data.csv', 
                            encoding = "ISO-8859-1",
                            dtype={'Div1Airport': str, 'Div1TailNum': str, 
                                   'Div2Airport': str, 'Div2TailNum': str})


# List of years 
year_list = [i for i in range(2005, 2021, 1)]

"""Compute graph data for creating yearly airline performance report 

Function that takes airline data as input and create 5 dataframes based on the grouping condition to be used for plottling charts and grphs.

Argument:
     
    df: Filtered dataframe
    
Returns:
   Dataframes to create graph. 
"""
def compute_data_choice_1(df):
    # Cancellation Category Count
    bar_data = df.groupby(['Month','CancellationCode'])['Flights'].sum().reset_index()
    # Average flight time by reporting airline
    line_data = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['AirTime'].mean().reset_index()
    # Diverted Airport Landings
    div_data = df[df['DivAirportLandings'] != 0.0]
    # Source state count
    map_data = df.groupby(['OriginState'])['Flights'].sum().reset_index()
    # Destination state count
    tree_data = df.groupby(['DestState', 'Reporting_Airline'])['Flights'].sum().reset_index()
    return [bar_data, line_data, div_data, map_data, tree_data]

"""Compute graph data for creating yearly airline delay report

This function takes in airline data and selected year as an input and performs computation for creating charts and plots.

Arguments:
    df: Input airline data.
    
Returns:
    Computed average dataframes for carrier delay, weather delay, NAS delay, security delay, and late aircraft delay.
"""
def compute_data_choice_2(df):
    # Compute delay averages
    avg_car = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['CarrierDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_weather = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['WeatherDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_NAS = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['NASDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_sec = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['SecurityDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_late = df.groupby(['Month','Reporting_Airline'])['LateAircraftDelay'].mean().reset_index()
    return [avg_car, avg_weather, avg_NAS, avg_sec, avg_late]

# Application layout
app.layout = (html.Div(children=[ 
                                # TODO1: Add title to the dashboard
                                html.H1('US Domestic Airline Flights Performance',
                                        style={'text-align-last':'centre','color':'#503D36','font-size':24}
                                       ),
                                # REVIEW2: Dropdown creation
                                # Create an outer division 
                                html.Div([
                                    # Add an division
                                    html.Div([
                                        # Create an division for adding dropdown helper text for report type   
                                        html.Div(
                                            [
                                            html.H2('Report Type:', style={'margin-right': '2em'})
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        # TODO2: Add a dropdown
                                        dcc.Dropdown(id='input-type',
                                                     options=[
                                                              {'label': 'Yearly Airline Performance Report', 'value': 'OPT1'},
                                                              {'label': 'Yearly Airline Delay Report', 'value': 'OPT2'}
                                                             ],
                                                     placeholder='Select a report type',
                                                     style={'width':'80%', 'padding':'3px', 'font-size':'20px', 'text-align-last':'center'}
                                                    )
                                    # Place them next to each other using the division style
                                            ], style={'display':'flex'}),
                                    
                                   # Add next division 
                                   html.Div([
                                       # Create an division for adding dropdown helper text for choosing year
                                        html.Div(
                                            [
                                            html.H2('Choose Year:', style={'margin-right': '2em'})
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        dcc.Dropdown(id='input-year', 
                                                     # Update dropdown values using list comphrehension
                                                     options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in year_list],
                                                     placeholder="Select a year",
                                                     style={'width':'80%', 'padding':'3px', 'font-size': '20px', 'text-align-last' : 'center'}),
                                            # Place them next to each other using the division style
                                            ], style={'display': 'flex'})  
                                          ]),
                                
                                # Add Computed graphs
                                # REVIEW3: Observe how we add an empty division and providing an id that will be updated during callback
                                html.Div([ ], id='plot1'),
    
                                html.Div([
                                          html.Div([ ], id='plot2'),
                                          html.Div([ ], id='plot3')
                                         ], 
                                          style={'display': 'flex'}),
                                
                                # TODO3: Add a division with two empty divisions inside. See above disvision for example.
                                html.Div([
                                          html.Div([ ], id='plot4'),
                                          html.Div([ ], id='plot5')
                                         ], 
                                          style={'display': 'flex'})
                                ])
             )

# Callback function definition
# TODO4: Add 5 ouput components
@app.callback( [Output(component_id='plot1', component_property='children'),
                Output(component_id='plot2', component_property='children'),
                Output(component_id='plot3', component_property='children'),
                Output(component_id='plot4', component_property='children'),
                Output(component_id='plot5', component_property='children')
               ],
               [Input(component_id='input-type', component_property='value'),
                Input(component_id='input-year', component_property='value')
               ],
               # REVIEW4: Holding output state till user enters all the form information. In this case, it will be chart type and year
               [State("plot1", 'children'), 
                State("plot2", "children"),
                State("plot3", "children"), 
                State("plot4", "children"),
                State("plot5", "children")
               ])

# Add computation to callback function and return graph
def get_graph(chart, year, children1, children2, c3, c4, c5):
      
        # Select data
        df =  airline_data[airline_data['Year']==int(year)]
       
        if chart == 'OPT1':
            # Compute required information for creating graph from the data
            bar_data, line_data, div_data, map_data, tree_data = compute_data_choice_1(df)
            
            # Number of flights under different cancellation categories
            bar_fig = px.bar(bar_data, x='Month', y='Flights', color='CancellationCode', title='Monthly Flight Cancellation')
            
            # TODO5: Average flight time by reporting airline
            line_fig = px.line(line_data, x='Month', y='AirTime', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average monthly flight time (minutes) by airline')
            
            # Percentage of diverted airport landings per reporting airline
            pie_fig = px.pie(div_data, values='Flights', names='Reporting_Airline', title='% of flights by reporting airline')
            
            # REVIEW5: Number of flights flying from each state using choropleth
            map_fig = px.choropleth(map_data,  # Input data
                    locations='OriginState', 
                    color='Flights',  
                    hover_data=['OriginState', 'Flights'], 
                    locationmode = 'USA-states', # Set to plot as USA States
                    color_continuous_scale='GnBu',
                    range_color=[0, map_data['Flights'].max()]) 
            map_fig.update_layout(
                    title_text = 'Number of flights from origin state', 
                    geo_scope='usa') # Plot only the USA instead of globe
            
            # TODO6: Number of flights flying to each state from each reporting airline
            tree_fig = px.treemap(tree_data, path=['DestState', 'Reporting_Airline'], 
                      values='Flights',
                      color='Flights',
                      color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                      title='Flight count by airline to destination state'
                )
            
            # REVIEW6: Return dcc.Graph component to the empty division
            return [dcc.Graph(figure=tree_fig), 
                    dcc.Graph(figure=pie_fig),
                    dcc.Graph(figure=map_fig),
                    dcc.Graph(figure=bar_fig),
                    dcc.Graph(figure=line_fig)
                   ]
        else:
            # REVIEW7: This covers chart type 2 and we have completed this exercise under Flight Delay Time Statistics Dashboard section
            # Compute required information for creating graph from the data
            avg_car, avg_weather, avg_NAS, avg_sec, avg_late = compute_data_choice_2(df)
            
            # Create graph
            carrier_fig = px.line(avg_car, x='Month', y='CarrierDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average carrrier delay time (minutes) by airline')
            weather_fig = px.line(avg_weather, x='Month', y='WeatherDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average weather delay time (minutes) by airline')
            nas_fig = px.line(avg_NAS, x='Month', y='NASDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average NAS delay time (minutes) by airline')
            sec_fig = px.line(avg_sec, x='Month', y='SecurityDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average security delay time (minutes) by airline')
            late_fig = px.line(avg_late, x='Month', y='LateAircraftDelay', color='Reporting_Airline', title='Average late aircraft delay time (minutes) by airline')
            
            return[dcc.Graph(figure=carrier_fig), 
                   dcc.Graph(figure=weather_fig), 
                   dcc.Graph(figure=nas_fig), 
                   dcc.Graph(figure=sec_fig), 
                   dcc.Graph(figure=late_fig)] 

   # Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # REVIEW8: Adding dev_tools_ui=False, dev_tools_props_check=False can prevent error appearing before calling callback function
    app.run_server(mode="inline", host='localhost', port=8050, debug=False, dev_tools_ui=False, dev_tools_props_check=False)
```

This is what I get

- Running on http://localhost:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2021 11:18:10] "GET /_alive_323f9ed8-1067-4501-9e4b-60eef6aaa56e HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Then a grey windows with a cloud saying localhost refused to connect

Comment: I have run your code in my environment. `app.run_server(mode="inline", debug=False)` I set the app's server settings to basic form only. I also disabled the Jupiter config and callback exclusion, `# JupyterDash.infer_jupyter_proxy_config()
` and as a result, I got two dropdowns, each with a tree diagram when I selected a value. `# app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True`

Comment: What can I do then? I'm clueless

Comment: Didn't editing the last line and commenting out two comments help? My environment has upgraded Dash to 2.0.0 this morning. What is the current version you are using?

Comment: I was using the Jupyter notebook of the learning platform, not sure about the update

Comment: I run the code and gave me a lot of errors, I'm not sure why this is happening...

Comment: If you can see the Colab environment and you modify your code to the same code as mine and get an error, I assume the problem is outside the Dash environment. I will remove my Colab code as it is not needed.